# Como acrescentar um caractere numa string, que já está dividida, a cada N caracteres?

Tags: javascript, split

Preciso saber como separar, em quebras de linha, uma string a cada N caracteres. No entanto, antes de separar a cada N caracteres, **elas já foram separadas a cada vírgula**.

> Quero que na saída essa separação seja quebra de linha.

Somente a vírgula é bem simples, basta um `split(",").join("\n")` que já resolve. Mas uma separação dentro de outra separação não consigo. Até penso em algumas soluções mas todas muito grandes, e para meu código preciso de algo simples.

Por exemplo, uma separação a cada 6 caracteres:

Entrada:

```
teste,testando,outro teste
```

Saída:

```
teste
testan
do
outro 
teste
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer a parte que falta pode utilizar uma regex, que seria o mais direto.

A regex seria:

```
/.{1,6}/g
```

Qualquer caratere (significado do `.`) com quantidade 1 a 6, aplicado de forma global (`g`). Quando usada com `match` vai lhe dar um array de resultados para cada 6 letras. De forma a ficar como mostrou basta fazer `join("\n")`, como tem no seu exemplo, que lhe vai dar um `\n` a cada 6 letras.

Então só a parte da aplicação da regex seria:

```
.match(/.{1,6}/g).join("\n")
```

O resto é a logica que já tem. Combinando tudo seria assim:

```js
let texto = "teste,testando,outro teste";
let resultados = texto.split(",").map(t => t.match(/.{1,6}/g).join("\n"));

alert(resultados.join("\n"));
```

Primeiro divide pela `,`, depois transforma cada resultado em conjuntos de `6` letras com a regex seguida de `join`. No fim mostra tudo junto com `join("\n")`.

Documentação:

- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)